# Turn a list of single-column SQL SELECT results into a single line

Tags: sqlite, sql

How can I make the statement:

```
SELECT column1 FROM db WHERE country in ('USA','BRA','CHN') and commodity='pork'
```

return

```
value1, value2, value3 (where value1 is for USA, value2 for BRA, value3 for CHN)
```

The best I got so far was a single column with all the values appearing as they are pulled from the database.

Comment: What output are you hoping to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
Select a.column1,b.column2,c.column3 from
(SELECT column1 FROM db WHERE country ='USA' and commodity='pork') as a,
(SELECT column1 FROM db WHERE country ='BRA' and commodity='pork') as b,
(SELECT column1 FROM db WHERE country ='CHN' and commodity='pork') as c
```

Comment: I thought it was working but I am actually getting SQLError: no such column: b.column2

Comment: if I replace for a.column1, b.column1, c.column1, I will get a giganting list of results. Something is not working right.

Comment: IF have many results for the query:SELECT column1 FROM db WHERE country ='USA' and commodity='pork. Or any of the others, it is complicated the solution, you need to pivot the table, if you want me to I can check how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for the GROUP_CONCAT() function:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

Comment: I did make the assumption that you're doing some type of commodity pricing and have a unique constraint on commodity/country combinations.  If this isn't the case you'll want to use one of the other answers provided with JOINs.

Comment: I understood your mistake, I wasnt clear enough. But so far none of the provided solutions work.

Answer (score 1):

Use sql pivot. This will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a presentation issue. 
Easier to let Python handle it:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('/path/to/your.db')
curs = conn.cursor()
results = curs.execute("""SELECT column1 
                            FROM db 
                           WHERE country in ('USA','BRA','CHN') 
                             AND commodity='pork';""").fetchall()
', '.join(str(result[0]) for result in results)
```

Comment: While I am normally heard pleading for OO programmers to use SQL for set maniplulation, this is a definate case for doing the processing in hte program!

Comment: @James Anderson: Why would you NOT want to solve this in the Database?

Comment: Because the SQL solutions are sub-optimal!  They dont scale, hard coding country codes in your SQL is a maintenence problem from day 1.  A simple python dictionary of the SQL results would be furure proof.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for Table Rotation. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766499/sql-table-joins-name-value-pairs/3766594#3766594) However I am not familiar with SQLLite so it might be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT column1 as value1 FROM db WHERE country='USA' and commodity='pork'
UNION
SELECT column1 as value2 FROM db WHERE country='BRA' and commodity='pork'
UNION
SELECT column1 as value3 FROM db WHERE country='CHN' and commodity='pork'
```

Comment: This does the exact same thing as what I already have: a long list of values. I am looking for getting these values side by side; in three columns.

Comment: @relima: My answer does not work. The answer given by mariana soffer is correct. Try it on http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_tryit.asp - "SELECT value1.ContactName, value2.ContactName FROM (SELECT ContactName FROM customers WHERE CompanyName='Centro comercial Moctezuma') as value1,
(SELECT ContactName FROM customers WHERE CompanyName='The Big Cheese') as value2"

Comment: If your answer does not work and is not helping anyone, please delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```
select 
  base.commodity
,USA_db.column1 as Commodity_USA
,BRA_db.column1 as Commodity_BRA
,CHN_db.column1 as Commodity_CHA
from (select 'pork' as commodity) as base
left join db as USA_db on base.commodity = USA_db.commodity and USA_db.country = 'USA'
left join db as BRA_db on base.commodity = BRA_db.commodity and BRA_db.country = 'BRA'
left join db as CHN_db on base.commodity = CHN_db.commodity and CHN_db.country = 'USA'
;
```

Output will be:

```
commodity   Commodity_USA  Commodity_BRA  Commodity_CHA
----------  -------------  -------------  -------------
pork        USA-pork       BRA-pork       USA-pork
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   select max(case country
                 when 'USA' then column1
                 else null
               end) USA,
           max(case country
                 when 'BRA' then column1
                 else null
               end) BRA,
           max(case country
                 when 'CHN' then column1
                 else null
               end) CHN
    FROM db
    WHERE country in ('USA','BRA','CHN')
     and commodity='pork'
```

One single pass over the data (single query), and you aggregate three rows, in other words nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work (Tested in mysql)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column1) FROM db WHERE country in ('USA','BRA','CHN') and commodity='pork'
```

my testing is this (in mysql)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( uid )  FROM pages where title in ('Home','Footer','home')
```

result:

```
1,3,10
```

this is correct..